# Coldfusion member function name matches jSoup function name. How can I force the use of jSoup function

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, coldfusion-2016

The following code which is used in Coldfusion 10 with jSoup works correctly:

```
var jsoup = application.jsoup;
var newBody = jsoup.parseBodyFragment(FileRead(expandPath("\default\includes\display_objects\custom\routesmapping\routePageTemplate.cfm")));
var routeBadge = newBody.select(".routeBadge");
routeBadge.append("<img src=""#$.content('decalFileName')#"" />");
```

On Coldfusion 2016 it errors on line 4, java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.jsoup.nodes.Element.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.jsoup.nodes.Element at
>   org.jsoup.select.Elements.add(Elements.java:15) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.ArrayUtil.ArrayAppend(ArrayUtil.java:208) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CFPage._arrayAppend(CFPage.java:578) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invokeMethodHandle(CfJspPage.ja‌​va:3198)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3155) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3072) at

It appears that it is using the ColdFusion member function, `append()`, added in CF11, instead of the jSoup `append()` function.

How can I force the use of the jSoup `append()` function over the CF `append()` member function in this situation?

Comment: The start of the Stacktrace eludes to the wrong append method being used. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.jsoup.nodes.Element at org.jsoup.select.Elements.add(Elements.java:15) at coldfusion.runtime.ArrayUtil.ArrayAppend(ArrayUtil.java:208) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage._arrayAppend(CFPage.java:578) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invokeMethodHandle(CfJspPage.java:3198) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3155) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3072) at

Comment: Works fine for me with "something.png".  What does `#$.content('decalFileName')#"` actually evaluate to? It should be a simple "String". Verify that is the case. (Also, insert boilerplate suggestion of adding `javacast()` to the argument here ;-).

Comment: The value of #$.content('decalFileName')# does evaluate to a simple string. I've tested it on my end replacing the variable with something.png and I get the same error? Possible differences in CF version? I'm on CF2016 Update 4. About to try the javacast() suggestion.

Comment: @Leigh Using javacast() resolved the issue for me. Thanks!
routeBadge.append(JavaCast("null", "<img src='something.png' />"));

Comment: Good, but it should be `javacast("string", ...)`. Otherwise, you are passing in `null`, rather than the `<img...>` text.

Comment: It is still giving the same error when I use javacast("string",...)

Comment: Well "null" means create a null element, which is not what you want. Can you give a runnable example I can try? Because it works for me under 2016., jsoup - 1.9.2

Comment: I'm on an older version of jSoup, so I'm going to update that. Here is my runnable example: 
    <cfscript>
jsoup = CreateObject("java","org.jsoup.Jsoup");
htmlstring = '<div id="main"><div class="routeBadge"></div></div>';
newBody = jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlstring);
routeBadge = newBody.select(".routeBadge");
routeBadge.append("<img src='something.png' />");
</cfscript>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146212/discussion-between-john-sieber-and-leigh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day, I was never able to get the jSoup append() method to work on any versions of CF11 or CF2016. I ended up having to switch to using the html() method and then concatenating my new string to the existing content.

So instead of:

```
descList.append("<dt>Booking Status:</dt><dd class = """ & statusClass & 
    """><em>#status#</em></dd>");
```

I had to use:

```
 descList.html(descList.html() & "<dt>Booking Status:</dt><dd class = """ & 
    statusClass & """><em>#status#</em></dd>");
```

Comment: Yeah, looking further .. that is definitely a bug.  append() works just fine when called with reflection. I would guess the implementation sees that [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) implements java.util.List, thinks it is a CF Array does not bother to check whether the Elements subclass has its own `append()` method that it should be calling instead. You should [file a Bug Report](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/home) as it could probably happen with other libs too.

Comment: @Leigh - Thanks for working through this with me. I've added a bug here: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198852